# Azure B2C configure OTP parameters using policies

Tags: azure, email, azure-ad-b2c, policies, totp

I'm trying to configure a B2C tenant using policies instead of user flows.For that, I'm using the [SocialAndLocalAccount](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts) template as start base. One of the things I'd like to do is to configure the email's verification parameters so I can choose the code's length, expiration time, etc. I don't really care about having a custom email like the example with [SendGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email), just want to be able to configure the basic parameters.

I've been following the [otp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/one-time-password-technical-profile) example they have in the documentation and managed to display the option properly but I never receive the email when clicking on "Send Code". Am I missing something? Is there another way to achieve this?

I'm new to Azure B2C and policies so I would appreciate any suggestions you might have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, if you want to use the custom OTP generation within B2C, you have to use an external mail provider. The built in email verification has a separate combined OTP and mail provider service that is not able to be decoupled.